# Linq to XML... null and missing elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML file

```
<Person>
<PersonItem id="0">
    <Time>1/8/2014</Time>
    <Step><![CDATA[Normal]]></Step>
    <HasAddress/>
    <Address/>
</PersonItem>
<PersonItem id="1">
    <Time>1/8/2014 3:21:45 PM</Time>
    <Step><![CDATA[Normal]]></Step>
    <HasAddress/>
    <Address/>
</PersonItem>
<PersonItem id="2">
    <Time>1/8/2014</Time>
    <Step><![CDATA[Normal]]></Step>
    <HasAddress>Main</HasAddress>
    <Address>
        <AddressItem id="0" location=5>
            <Address>15 Oak</Address>
        </AddressItem>
        <AddressItem id="1" location=7>
            <Address>12 Maple</Address>
        </AddressItem>
        <AddressItem id="2" location=8>
            <Address>30 Beech</Picture>
        </AddressItem>
    </Address>
</PersonItem>
</Person>
```

I want to put to retrieve the information and send some of it to a database. I've tried several different ways of dealing with this and I believe I'm close. Here is the Linq I tried.

```
public void DoIt(fileName)
{
    XElement xml = XElement.Load(fileName);

    var items = from item in xml.Elements("PersonItem")
                where (from x in item.Elements("HasAddress")
                       where  x.Element("HasAddress") != null
                       select x).Any()
                select item;

    Array.ForEach(items.ToArray(),
        o=>Console.WriteLine(o.Element("Time").Value));
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

The problem is nothing is being returned.

Answer (score 1):

Could be just a typo but in your xml file there is this tag error.

```
<Address>30 Beech</Picture>
```

which should be:

```
<Address>30 Beech</Address>
```

Comment: With the typo fixed I can use @MarcinJuraszek's code without the xml.Root.Elements, just xml.Elements and I get the result I think you're looking for.

Comment: I also use your Load with XElement xml = XElement.Load(fileName); instaed of his.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
XElement xml = XElement.Load(fileName);
var items = xml.Descendants("PersonItem")
               .Where(x => (string)x.Element("HasAddress") != null)
               .Select(x => x);
```

Comment: I get no data returned "Enumeration yielded no results"

Answer (score 0):

```
XDocument xml = XDocument.Load("Input.xml");

var items = from item in xml.Root.Elements("PersonItem")
            where !string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)item.Element("HasAddress"))
            select item;
```

For your sample XML document returns only the last `PersonItem` element.

Comment: How would I see all of the elements and the PersonItem id and the AddressItem id for the last PersonItem elements like "time" and "Address"

Comment: You can perform another query on returned `items` which is `IEnumerable<XElement>` with all matched `PersonItem` elements.

Comment: items has the value of "Enumeration yielded no results" so there is nothing to query